# How to use my own button for "next" and "previous" instead button generated on runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

This code is adding a span on runtime to change the slide. If I'm on left side of screen it add the span with "previous" and if I'm on right side on the screen it adds span with "next"

```
(function(){
    var scaler=Scaler('bg'),els=$('#bg').children(),width=100/els.length;
    var float=$('<span />').css({position:'absolute',color:'#fff',cursor:'pointer',zIndex:2});
    var div=$('<div/>').css({position:'absolute',left:0,bottom:0,marginRight:-20,height:'100%'});
    div.width(els.css({float:'left',width:width+'%'}).length+'00%').append(els);

    var move=function(e){
            float[0].style.left=(e=e||window.event).clientX+20+'px';
            float[0].style.top=e.clientY+20+'px';
            if(float[0].nxt!=(e.clientX>(document.body.offsetWidth/2)))float[0].innerHTML=(float[0].nxt=!float[0].nxt)?'next':'previous';   //Change html only if needed
        },
        swap=function(e){
            var key=e.type=='click'?(e.clientX>(document.body.clientWidth/2)?40:37):e.keyCode;
            if(key>36&&key<41)div.animate({left:(scaler(key>38?'+1':'-1').to*-1)+'00%'});   //swap with animation
        }

    $(window).bind('keydown',swap);
    $('#bg').bind('mousemove',move).bind('click',swap).css('cursor','pointer').append(div,float);

    /*$('#bg').cycle({ //if using jquery.cycle-plugin the window resizing won't behave too good - fixable
        timeout:2000,
        after:function(a,b,c){scaler(c.currSlide)}, //but this part is important - scale the current photo
        fx:'scrollLeft'
    });*/
})();
```

I want change this behavior. I have my own button in markup called "next" and "previous" which are fixed at left and right side on screen.

```
<div class="previous">Previous</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
```

Can anyone change this code to remove the  functionality which add the span on runtime and to give me the facility to use my own Links which are always available on the page.

**I added working JS fiddle here**

### http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/j66Fj/1/

Comment: Umm, try removing `float` from the very last line (not the commented out part) so you end up with this - `.append(div);` instead of `.append(div,float);` and see if that works. It would be easier to help if you had a working demo.

Comment: @fudgey - i added fiddle to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this change for the jQuery/JavaScript. This works on my browser which is Chrome.

```
(function(){
    var scaler=Scaler('bg'),els=$('#bg').children(),width=100/els.length;
    var float=$('<span />').css({position:'absolute',color:'#fff',cursor:'pointer',zIndex:2});
    var div=$('<div/>').css({position:'absolute',left:0,bottom:0,marginRight:-20,height:'100%'});
    div.width(els.css({float:'left',width:width+'%'}).length+'00%').append(els);

    var move=function(e){
            float[0].style.left=(e=e||window.event).clientX+20+'px';
            float[0].style.top=e.clientY+20+'px';
            //if(float[0].nxt!=(e.clientX>(document.body.offsetWidth/2)))float[0].innerHTML=(float[0].nxt=!float[0].nxt)?'next':'previous';   //Change html only if needed
        },
        swap=function(e){
            var key=e.type=='click'?(e.clientX>(document.body.clientWidth/2)?40:37):e.keyCode;
            if(key>36&&key<41)div.animate({left:(scaler(key>38?'+1':'-1').to*-1)+'00%'});   //swap with animation
        }

    $(window).bind('keydown',swap);
    $('#bg').css('cursor','pointer').append(div,float);
        //bind('mousemove',move).bind('click',swap).css('cursor','pointer').append(div,float);

    /*$('#bg').cycle({ //if using jquery.cycle-plugin the window resizing won't behave too good - fixable
        timeout:2000,
        after:function(a,b,c){scaler(c.currSlide)}, //but this part is important - scale the current photo
        fx:'scrollLeft'
    });*/
    $(".next").click(function(){
        $("#bg").trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 39 }));
    });
            $(".previous").click(function(){
        $("#bg").trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 37 }));
    });
})();
```

Comment: +1 Great help Yeah it's working on my example. but in my actual project it's not working. is the position in source code of next and previous button related to this?

Comment: Jiten, what the change in the code does is to remove the click and mousemove actions to the div#bg. The code also generates a keydown event on click of next and previous. They are right arrow key and left arrow key press events. I would like to know if you see any error in JavaScript console.

Comment: Yes your code removed the click and mousemove functions from #bg but my next and previous button not working.

Comment: I got the problem. It's working. Actually in my project I was using jQuery 1.4.2 and I made JSfiddle using 1.6.4.